# Files in DatagridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How can I show files and their path in DataGridView without using web page? 
I want to display all sub folders of file I've selected with FolderBrowserDialog in one column and their path in second column. I tried to found out how it's possible, but I've found only examples in VB.net and they were using web pages for it. I want to use WinForm for display the data.

Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get list of files and folders use the methods of `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` or `System.IO.Directory` class.

```
var result = from file in 
                   new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:\").EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
                   select file;

dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for fast response, I tried your code and it gives me this error: 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' does not contain a definition for 'EnumerateFileSystemInfos' and no extension method 'EnumerateFileSystemInfos' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I don't know what should I do.

Comment: I've solved it yet,I've just changed 'EnumerateFileSystemInfos' to 'GetFiles' and it works now, so thanks very much.