# Load a DataGridView with a directory listing

Tags: c#, datagridview, directory

I found an answer to my question here
[Files in DatagridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709910/files-in-datagridview)

The trouble is I don't understand it.
The c# code is so brief I can't figure out what it is doing.  It is one thing to cut and paste code that works but if I don't understand it at all I don't learn anything.

```
class looseFilesImport
{
    public static  int loadLooseFilesDataGridView(DataGridView dgv, string folderPath)
    {
        var result = from file in new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folderPath).GetFiles() select file;

        dgv.DataSource = result.ToList();

        return 0;
     }
```

Is there a way to expand the line starting with "var result =" into a more readable form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That LINQ query is pointless.  Just do this:

```
dgv.DataSource = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folderPath).GetFiles();
```

The method can be declared `void` and get rid of the `return` statement too.

It's simply getting a `FileInfo` object for each file in a folder and then displaying the results in the grid with a column for each property of the `FileInfo` class.  The LINQ query does nothing useful and nor does the return value.

In case you're unaware, setting the `DataSource` property of the grid sets up data-binding, meaning that any changes to the data source are automatically reflected in the grid and vice versa.  There aren't really going to be any changes in this case but it's still the most convenient way to load data into a grid.  When you bind a `DataGridView` it will automatically create any missing columns by default.

Comment: OK That is even more brief :) but it is clearer I guess.  The return is just there as I'm going to put a try catch in there and return an error number if it fails.

Comment: Great answer.  I'm a bit of a program by example kind of guy and after years of plodding along all of this stuff is staring to fall into place.  The line you have provided looks much more sensible.  Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Blurgh!  Sounds like VB6 error handling.  If the caller needs to deal with the error then it should be catching the exception.

Comment: That makes sense too :)  My first programing language was Cobol so I have many habits that some would now consider "Blurgh"  I was starting to wonder where the best place to put the try and catch blocks is.  What I really want in my code is to be consistent and understandable to others and not too much laughter!

Comment: Can we make row clickable ? , On click of file name open file or directory

Comment: @Saurabh, the rows are already clickable. If you want to do something when a the click occurs then you simply handle the appropriate event and perform the appropriate action. If you want to know what events a `DataGridView` has and when they are raised, read the MSDN documentation for the `DataGridView` class.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks